# Cannot set property 'baseUrl' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, nswag

I have generated a javascript client using NSWAG from a ASP .NET Rest API. But I am finding a few errors when I am trying to call an API method.

The error in cause is: TypeError: Cannot set property 'baseUrl' of undefined.

```
var AuthClient = (function () {
    function AuthClient($http, baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = undefined;
        this.http = null;
        this.jsonParseReviver = undefined;
        this.http = $http;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl !== undefined ? baseUrl : "";
    };
    AuthClient.prototype.login = function (auth) {
        var _this = this;
        var url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/v1/auth/login";
        var content_ = JSON.stringify(auth ? auth.toJS() : null);
        return this.http({
            url: url_,
            method: "POST",
            data: content_,
            transformResponse: [],
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                "Accept": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            return _this.processLogin(response);
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.status)
                return _this.processLogin(response);
            throw response;
        });
    };
...}());
exports.AuthClient = AuthClient;
```

In my angular code I am doing:

```
    var client = AuthClient('http://localhost:14959/');
    var call = client.prototype.login(data);
```

I have already debugged the application and it enters the function AuthClient and I have also tried to change it to this, but the problem persists:

```
function AuthClient($http, baseUrl) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
};
```

I am also getting this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` I don't know if it has something to do with it or not. If not just ignore.

Error trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'baseUrl' of undefined
    at AuthClient (RenterLogApiBackendClient.js:19)
    at b.$scope.login (HomeController.js:16)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:1), <anonymous>:4:206)
    at b (angular.js:16123)
    at e (angular.js:26490)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:17913)
    at b.$apply (angular.js:18013)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26495)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `AuthClient` function, you need to actually return your constructor, and then call it using `new`:

```
var AuthClient = (function () {
    // ...

    return AuthClient;
}());

var client = new AuthClient('http://localhost:14959/');
```

You can probably omit the `exports` line.

Answer (score 1):

This line is not required:

```
this.baseUrl = undefined;
```

If you again have this:

```
this.baseUrl = baseUrl !== undefined ? baseUrl : "";
```

Best way to do this is to:

```
this.baseUrl = '' || this.baseUrl;
```

And in `AuthClient` you have two parameters, out of which the second parameter is `baseUrl`. But when you are setting it, you are using only one parameter.

So define another function inside that and then use the parameter.

Comment: As I said, I tried only this: function AuthClient($http, baseUrl) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
}; and got the same error

Comment: The suggestion is backwards; should be `this.baseUrl = baseUrl || "";`.

Comment: @RuiQueirós Yes, that is because you have two parameters in `AuthClient`. Instead define another method inside `AuthClient` with `baseUrl` as parameter. ANd call that method for the `post` call

Comment: It does not matter, the same thing will happen. I will update my question with the complete stack.